# PfCreateInterface returns error 120 (not implemented)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ip

I need to create a simple IP filtering program for Windows; however, I am having problems getting the relevant API call to work. Below is a small example demonstrating how `PfCreateInterface` fails. It is returning `120` which is the system error code `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. I am running the program on Windows 10.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#include <Fltdefs.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")

int main()
{
    INTERFACE_HANDLE hInterface;
    PFFORWARD_ACTION action = PF_ACTION_FORWARD;

    DWORD errorCode = PfCreateInterface(0,
        action,
        action,
        FALSE,
        TRUE,
        &hInterface);

    std::cout << "errorCode = " << errorCode << std::endl;    
}
```

Can somebody explain why it is failing? If I can't use it on Windows 10, do you know what is the alternative API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa376646(v%3Dvs.85)) is pretty clear:

> PfCreateInterface is available for use in the operating systems listed
>   in the Requirements section.

The Windows versions "listed in the Requirements section" are Windows Server 2003 or Windows 2000 Server.

So this API call is essentially obsolete. The documentation recommends using [the Windows Filtering Platform management functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/fwp-mgmt-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead.